# Implementing PyObjc NsObject Subclass

Tags: python, cocoa, xcode, pyobjc

I have an Objc-C project in which I would like to be able to process some data trough Python. For that, I decided to implement a PyObjc NSObject subclass, which I would then link to my Obj-C classes trough the interface builder.

I added the Python framework to my project, and an python file with the following simple code:

```
import objc
from Foundation import *
from AppKit import *

class PythonWrapper(NSObject):
    def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, sender):
        NSLog("Application did finish launching.")
```

I created a PythonWrapper instance in my XIB (the builder automatically recognized the name of it). But, when building, even without having linked it already to the other classes, I get the following issue:

> Ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks//Python.framework/Python, missing required architecture x86_64 in file

Also, the xCode log also shows:

> Unknown class 'PythonWrapper', using 'NSObject' instead. Encountered in Interface Builder file at path /Users/joao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Jalioneiro-ekjwzbkqqgpyekadkyebhgdsjcxo/Build/Products/Debug/Jalioneiro.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Interface.nib.

What am I missing here? Is there any other way to link python code to my Obj-C classes?

**Note:** I'm working on xCode4

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that Xcode 4 does not play so nicely with PyObjC, but I'm still using 3, so I can't be sure.

The reason for your second error (and this bites me too *all the time*) is that you need to import your custom classes into your project's main.py:

```
#import modules required by application
import objc
import Foundation
import AppKit

from PyObjCTools import AppHelper

# import modules containing classes required to start application and load MainMenu.nib
import MyAppDelegate
import MyCustomView
import MyArrayController

# pass control to AppKit
AppHelper.runEventLoop()
```

The first error looks like you're trying to build a 64-bit-only application. The PyObjC that shipped with Snow Leopard is only compiled as 32-bit (actually, I think the same is true of the default Python). Try switching your Target's build architecture to either 32-bit or 32/64-bit Universal. You could also go down the path of re-compiling PyObjC and including it in your app's bundle -- haven't tried it myself.